# Class not found with Laravel, using PhpStorm. Weird behaviour

Tags: laravel, composer-php, phpstorm

I have been struggling for quite a while; I finally fixed my issue, but I can't understand: "why". I have this folder structure:

```
/app 
/many folders... 
/tests 
/tests/functional/ (which contains some tests) 
/tests/BaseClassA.php 
/tests/BaseClassB.php
```

Everything was working correctly, some functional tests were inheriting `BaseClassA`. (I know it's not an autoload issue). Then I decided to create `BaseClassB.php`, so `BaseClassA extends BaseClassB`.

I copied `BaseClassA.php` file, removed stuff; kept what I wanted in the `BaseClassB` file. I run `composer dump-autload`, but I kept having the message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Tests\BaseClassB' not found in ...BaseClassA.php.

Both files are in the same folder, with the same namespace.
Why does it not find the class ?

So, I deleted the file BaseClassB, (remember I copied it); to create it another way: I right clicked: "create new Class" and typed BaseClassB. The file had the same structure, PhpStorm found the class (I mean no import warning in the IDE). But runtime still fails (even after running composer dump-autoload): still `Error: class not found ...`

I noticed that in PhpStorm the file icon is a *C with lightblue background*, when my other classes have a *php icon*.

**Q1: Why? All my other files are classes too, why is this one shown differently?**

This icon difference bothered me, so I deleted the file again and hit the :"create new php file", in which I copy-pasted the content of my very first file. And it suddenly worked.

Did anyone experienced something like this already ? I'm pretty sure the namespaces and so on were written correctly the first time, because:

1. PhpStorm did not give colored warning in code
2. It worked when I copy-paste the code in the new created file on 3rd attempt.

**Q2: How are the "create new class" and "create new php file" different ?**

I ask this because it was frustrating (it looks like 3 attempts, but it took me hours to find that out...)

Comment: laravel uses namespaces, not folder structure for including classes.

Comment: i know, i just gave the folder structure for information, but as stated, all namespaces are defined correctly. (according to the file structure: PSR0 if i'm not wrong)

Comment: *"Q1: Why ? All my other files are classes too, why is this one shown differently ?"* Few conditions should be met to show a `(C)` or `(I)` or `(T)` or `(Exception)` etc icon instead of generic PHP: 1) Only one class/interface/trait declared in a file 2) Class/Interface/etc name must match the file name. Check capitalisation as well (since your PHP is unable to find it).

Comment: *"Q2: How are the "create new class" and "create new php file" different ?"* "New File" creates just an empty .php file (well, by default with some header); In "New Class" dialog you can easily switch between class/interface/trait; quickly edit namespace; can have different file name to the actual class name etc.

Comment: @XSA, I'd like to indicate that laravel internally uses composer auto-loading functionality, so you must check the autoloading configuration in your `composer.json`  before dumping the autoload via composer command-line.

Comment: If it would be purely PhpStorm error (it cannot find something but it actually works when executing it) then you could try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE. But here PHP itself was complaining .. so it most likely the issue with capitalisation (on case sensitive file system) .. or some invisible characters were added in filename/class name (IDE does not show them as "unknown" character -- unless you install some 3rd party plugin that will show errors in such places ("Zero-width characters" it's called -- or something like that)